# Reload page with Javascript when count down reaches 0

Tags: javascript

I m using the below function to display a count down and would like to reload the page when the counter reaches `0`. 
I just sat and watched the counter hit 0 and nothing happened. Isn't `location.reload()` suppose to refresh the page?

```
function secondPassed() {
    var numDays = Math.floor(seconds / 86400);
    var numHours = Math.floor((seconds % 86400) / 3600);
    var numMinutes = Math.floor(((seconds % 86400) % 3600) / 60);
    var numSeconds = ((seconds % 86400) % 3600) % 60;

    if (numSeconds < 10) {
        numSeconds = "0" + numSeconds; 
    }

    document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = "<span class='fa fa-clock-o' aria-hidden='true'></span> " 
            + ('' + numDays).slice(-2) + "d " + "" 
            + ('' + numHours).slice(-2) + "h " + "" 
            + ('' + numMinutes).slice(-2) + "m " + "" 
            + ('' + numSeconds).slice(-2) + "s ";

    if (seconds <= 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        location.reload();
    } else {
        seconds--;
    }
}

setInterval(function () {
    secondPassed();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Did you get any errors in the console? I've made a jsfiddle with your code, initialized the `seconds` variable, and assigned `countdownTimer` to the setInterval function) and it worked. Working jsFiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/fabio_silva/5sgnc818/](https://jsfiddle.net/fabio_silva/5sgnc818/)

Comment: I didn't look and I don't have that page open anymore. I ll look for any errors.

Comment: Your `countdownTimer` is *undefined* when you are trying to `clearInterval` and hence `reload` is not called because execution is aborted.

Comment: so would it be ok to comment that piece out since i want to reload the page anyway? It just stops the counter ... right?

Comment: @ciprian Yep, if you just remove the `clearInterval(countdownTimer);` it should work.

Comment: @dreyescat - Tested and confirmed your answer.  Perhaps you should post it so OP can give you credit?

Comment: @Roberto You are right. And then the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I promoted my comment to answer as it was actually describing the issue.

Your `countdownTimer` is *undefined* when you are trying to `clearInterval` and hence `reload` is not called because execution is aborted.

Just remove the offending `clearInterval` and it will work.

```
    if (seconds <= 0) {
            // >> clearInterval(countdownTimer);
            location.reload();
    } else {
            seconds--;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try like this

```
/*
    if true page will always reload from server
    else page will load from cache
*/
window.location.reload(true);
```

Comment: I don't think it is the issue... I don't think it needs to be reloaded from server.